# php load page page into div ,java script not working

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i am using ajax to load pages into a div
the page is loading fine 
but i cant run the php  and javascript 
in that loaded page

in server i am loading the page like this

```
file_get_contents('../' . $PAGE_URL);
```

in the browser i am setting the content of the div 
using

```
eval("var r = " + response.responseText);
```

and setting the innerHTML for that div 
with the retrieve information 
but when i get the new inner page 
no php or java script is working

is that suppose to be like that ?

Comment: php gives me an error when i am trying to include my page :     

[Thu Aug 05 15:38:01 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] <br/><br/>Unexpexted output: \r\n<html>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src

Comment: Why don't you edit your question and add the code you tried and the error.

Answer (score 2):

Well the php is not going to work I think because the way you are handling it, it is just text.  I would suggest using something like `include('../' . $PAGE_URL);` and that should parse the php.
  The javascript problem probably has to do with the fact that you are loading `<html> <body> <head>` tags in a div I'm not sure what happens when you do that, but it shouldn't work properly.  Try using some type of `<frame>` tag.

Comment: i remove all html and body tags and added frame surrounding all
in my server i place the 'include' method before the 'file_get_contents' 
but now i dont see the page at all

Comment: Don't use the `file_get_contents` just use the `include`.  But why don't you use a `frame` or `iframe`? Use javascript to add the element and then set its source to whatever file you need.  This would work fine unless there is some reason you need to call the page from the server.

Comment: i have problem includeing my file 
[Thu Aug 05 15:21:24 2010] [error] [client 10.0.0.2] <br/><br/>Unexpexted output: \r\n\r\n\r\n<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/.....

Answer (score 1):

In order for your javascript to be executed properly, you have to wait until the browser has finished to load the page.

This event is named `onload()`. Your code should be executed on this event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file = false;

    if(isset($_GET['load'] && is_string($_GET['load'])) {
        $tmp = stripclashes($_GET['load']);
        $tmp = str_replace(".","",$tmp);

        $file = $tmp . '.php';
    }

    if($file != false && file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        require_once $file;
    }

?>
```

called via file.php?load=test

That process the PHP file, and as long as you spit out HTML from the file simply

```
target = document.getElementById('page');    
target.innerHTML = response.responseText;
```

Now, i'm fairly certain parts of that are insecure, you could have a whitelist of allowable requires. It should ideally be looking in a specific directory for the files also. I'm honestly not all too sure about directly dumping the responseText back into a DIV either, security wise as it's ripe for XSS. But it's the end of the day and I haven't looked up anything on that one. Be aware, without any kind of checking on this, you could have a user being directed to a third party site using file_get_contents, which would be a Very Bad Thing. You could eval in PHP a file_get_contents request, which... is well, Very Very Bad. For example try

```
<?php
     echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");
?>
```

But I fear I must ask here, why are you doing it this way? This seems a very roundabout way to achieve a Hyperlink.

Is this AJAX for AJAXs sake?

Comment: i have a menu on the left side , instead of loading the full html includes the menues , i am requesting only to replace the content div ,using ajax , i was able to do this like this 


function getPageContent(&$response){
  $PAGE_URL     = $_POST['PAGE_URL'];

  ob_start();
  require_once( '../' . $PAGE_URL );
  $contents = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  $response->fields->frame_main = $contents;
  
}

but i have to separate my javascript to the main page , 
is there a way to avoid that ?